# Prove carefully that $g(f(x)) \rightarrow l$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Suppose that (i) $f(x) \rightarrow y_0$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$, (ii) $g(y) \rightarrow l$ as $y\rightarrow y_0$ and (iii) $g(y_0)=l$. Prove carefully that $g(f(x)) \rightarrow l$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$

---

Largely confused because it seems to me very straightforward. My professor is telling me that he wants more than a simple notational re-write (which is what it looks like to me).

Can someone give me a hint as to how to "rigorously" prove this? I am currently just re-writing the definition of the limit of a function in three different ways.

EDIT: the definition that I am working with

"*Suppose $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f(x) \rightarrow y_0$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$, then $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists\delta >0 s.t. \forall x \in E$ s.t. $|x-x_0|<\delta$*

$|f(x)-y_0|<\varepsilon$

Comment: What is the rigorous definition that you have for "$f(x)\rightarrow y_0$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$"?  Whatever definition you have (may there are some $\epsilon$'s in there, for example), you should prove that $g(f(x))\rightarrow l$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$ with respect to this same definition.

Comment: I can prove it but I cannot promise I'll be careful.

Comment: As written, it need not be true. Consider $f$ the identity function on the irrationals, $g$ the identity function on the rationals, and $x_0=y_0=l=0.$ Then all three conditions hold, but $g(f(x))$ is undefined everywhere, so we certainly can't talk about its limits. Is there some context you've left out of the problem?

Comment: Perhaps $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,$ or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

(*) There is a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|y - y_0|<\delta_1$ implies $|g(y) - l| < \epsilon$.

Using $\delta_1$ in the definition of limit for $f(x) \to y_0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - y_0| < \delta_1$; for such $x$, by (*) with $y = f(x)$, we have
$$
|g(f(x)) - l| < \epsilon.
$$ 
Therefore, $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies $|g(f(x)) - y_0| < \epsilon$.